# Cant return value in JQuery recursion

Tags: jquery, recursion

Please help to understand what I'm doing wrong:
I have DOM structure:

```
<div class="wraper">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="field_regions[und][8260]" value="8260" class="form-checkbox">               
    <label class="option" for="edit-field-regions-und-8260">Europe </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="field_regions[und][8260]" value="8260" class="form-checkbox">               
    <label class="option" for="edit-field-regions-und-8260">- East Europe </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="field_regions[und][8260]" value="8260" class="form-checkbox">               
    <label class="option" for="edit-field-regions-und-8260">-- Romania </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I need is to find first parent of checked element. (for Romania it will be - East Europe).

I have following JS:

```
    // Force hierarchy checking.
    var selectors3 = terms.find('.form-type-checkbox');
    for (var i3 = 0, len3 = selectors3.length ; i3 < len3 ; i3++) {
      $(selectors3[i3]).bind('click', function() {              
      var test = findParent(this);
      console.log(test);
      });
    }

  function findParent(a) {
    var selector = $(a).prev();
    if (selector.find('label').text().indexOf('-')) {
      return selector;          
    }
    else {
      findParent(selector.prev(a));
    }
  }
```

This function returns me "Undefined". Where can be the problem?

Comment: your calss selector `form-type-checkbox` is wrong, it should be `.form-checkbox`

Comment: East Europe is not parent of Romania BTW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using class name as form-type-checkbox in below line

```
var selectors3 = terms.find('.form-type-checkbox');
```

but in actual your checkbox is having class name as form-checkbox

and return value from recursive function call i.e.

```
return findParent(selector.prev(a));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to **return** the value from the recursion:

```
else {
    return findParent(selector.prev(a));  // You're missing the 'return' here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed your input have class 
form-checkbox
, but your jquery code uses this .form-type-checkbox selector, is it what you want?